# phpcs error in WordPress

Tags: nonce

I'm working with the MegaMenu here `echo wp_nonce_url()` is showing an error `All output should run through an escaping function` according to wpcs. I gave `echo esc_url( wp_nonce_url())` Is it correct? Point me where am I going wrong.

[image]

Comment: `esc_url()` is correct. Did it not work?

Comment: @Jacob Peattie yeah it is working fine. thanks, I just want to know it is correct or not according to the WordPress standards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is correct. Escaping should be done based on context, and since `wp_nonce_url()` is used in an `href`as proper url, you should use `esc_url`.